# Please provide the prefix of GraphicsMagick installation [autodetect]

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, pear, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to install the PHP API for [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) using this pecl command:

```
sudo pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/gmagick-1.0.10b1
```

during installation I am asked this question:

```
Please provide the prefix of GraphicsMagick installation [autodetect]
```

I have no idea how to answer this and if I just press enter for auto detection the install fails.

```
checking whether to enable the gmagick extension... yes, shared
checking GraphicsMagick configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to GraphicsMagick-config program.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gmagick/configure --with-gmagick' failed
```

I am using ubuntu server, does anyone know how I can install this program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try installing the `libgraphicsmagick1-dev` package (sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick1-dev). That should give you GraphicsMagick-config in /usr/bin.

When trying to figure out what package is needed for a particular file running `apt-file search <filename>` helps. So in this case `apt-file search GraphicsMagick-config` which on Ubuntu Server 11.04 gives:

```
% apt-file search GraphicsMagick-config    
libgraphicsmagick1-dev: /usr/bin/GraphicsMagick-config
libgraphicsmagick1-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/GraphicsMagick-config.1.gz
```

Comment: thanks so much dude, after installing using the command you gave and then using the pecl command I posted earlier and entering /usr/bin/GraphicsMagick-config on the prompt the install went fine. Cheers.

Comment: For the record, after installing the libgraphicsmagick1-dev package, I didn't need to enter the path to the config command, just pressing enter for autodetect worked perfectly.

Comment: Any fix for this for Mac OS Mavericks?

Comment: On OS X run brew install GraphicsMagick and then rerun the command

Answer (score 0):

On OS X simply run

> brew install GraphicsMagick

and then rerun the pecl installation command

Comment: on Centos / REHL: `yum install GraphicsMagick-devel`